# TNS-12514: TNS:прослушиватель в данный момент не имеет данных о службе, запрашиваемой в дескрипторе соединения

Tags: sql, oracle

Всем доброго времени суток, проблема следующая, придя сегодня на работу обнаружил что база упала, стал перезапускать службы и т.д, но получаю ошибку **TNS-12514: TNS:прослушиватель в данный момент не имеет данных о службе, запрашиваемой в дескрипторе соединения.** Прикладываю всё что есть
**listener.ora**

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      #(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MMK-T-0198)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.137.249)(PORT = 1521))
     # (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.205.232.54)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\Oracle
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.137.249)(PORT = 1521)) #MMK-T-0198
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SID = orcl)
    )
  )
```

**sqlnet.ora**

```
# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES,EZCONNECT)
```

Лог **alert/log.xml**

```
<msg time='2016-08-29T14:50:37.279+03:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='MMK-T-0198'
 host_addr='fe80::19f4:5e4e:a0c0:8645%11'>
 <txt>29-АВГ-2016 14:50:37 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=MMK-T-0198$))(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.137.249)(PORT=1446)) * establish * orcl * 12571
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2016-08-29T14:50:47.280+03:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='MMK-T-0198'
 host_addr='fe80::19f4:5e4e:a0c0:8645%11'>
 <txt>TNS-12571: TNS:сбой программы записи в пакете
 TNS-12560: TNS:ошибка адаптера протокола
  TNS-00530: Ошибка адаптера протокола
   64-bit Windows Error: 54: Unknown error
    TNS-12514: TNS:прослушиватель в данный момент не имеет данных о службе, запрашиваемой в дескрипторе соединения
 </txt>
</msg>
```

lsnrctl status Зависает. tnsping либо ошибка, либо время отклика до 3 мин.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем дело, база перед уходом на выходные работала.

Comment: Возможно база не поднялась. Статус базы какой? Доступ к машине с базой есть, через sqlplus подключается?

Comment: @IDrakonl да через sqlplus конектится. Заметил что при перезагрузке служба OracleService не может сам запустится. Подробнее про статус базы пожалуйста ?

Comment: `select status from v$instance;` что возвращает? Есть предположение, что база после падения просто не стартанула листенер не видит ее

Comment: @lDrakonl STATUS OPEN

Comment: @lDrakonl Уже сделал реконфиг listener не помогает. Что бы я не делал получаю ошибку TNS-12514. И как поднять базу не понимаю, вроде бы и всё запущено а listener не видно

Comment: `select name from v$database` результат покажите. И ОС какая? Посмотрел по подробнее. Возможно листенер сломался. Попробуйте создать новый листенер, а старый остановите.

Comment: @lDrakonl при наборе вашей команды в sqlplus пишет STATUS OPEN больше ничего нет. ОС win 2008 server R2 Enterprise

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44662/discussion-between-ldrakonl-and-ethernets).

Comment: @lDrakonl не получается в чат зайти

Comment: Что не так с чатом? Можно тогда телеграмм использовать

Comment: @lDrakonl Я в чате. Спасибо

Comment: Вы пытаетесь проверить доступность листенера БД Oracle с localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NikolayBaranenko Большое вам спасибо за ответ. Проблема была решена. И на 90% проблемой было переполнение логов listener.log. Остальные 10% решило отключение IPv6. Также большое спасибо @lDrakonl за участие в решении проблемы.